# Hugo Data Templates That Contain Title of Page

Tags: html, static, markdown, hugo

When using [Hugo](https://gohugo.io), is it possible to display a data template using the `.Title` function? For example, here is my data template function `<p>{{.Site.Data.config.TextOne}}</p>`. It grabs the string `TextOne` from my data template file in the directory **/data**. However, I want to be able to use the title of the page or a variable in the place of `.TextOne`. Kind of this `{{.Site.Data.config.Title}}`. That of course doesn't work.

What might be alternatives or solutions to this request?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Allowing the function to operate separately with the `.Title` function and calling the `index` I was able to call strings of data based on the title of the page.

`<p>{{index .Site.Data.config .Title}}</p>`

Documentation this can be found of [Hugo's docs website](https://gohugo.io/templates/data-templates/).